# Problemas com Divider no Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Boa noite!! Estou criando um feed de uma rede social com o Flutter, e me encontro com um problema na exibição das imagens. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Divider deveria aparecer entre as duas imagens, porém, o que está acontecendo é que ele pega as duas imagens que tenho em uma coleção do Firebase, e repete elas dividindo com o Divider. 
Segue o código:

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          future: Firestore.instance.collection("fotos").getDocuments(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(!snapshot.hasData){
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.deepOrange),
                )
              );
            }else{
              return ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return Column(
                    children: snapshot.data.documents.map(
                      (doc){
                        return Container(
                          child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                          placeholder: kTransparentImage, 
                          image: doc.data["urlImagem"],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        );
                      }
                    ).toList()
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                  height: 50,
                  thickness: 0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              );
            }
          },
        )
```

O que posso fazer para que a cada imagem recuperada no Firestore, seja dividida com um Divider ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está jogando todas as imagens em um `Column` e dessa forma só depois que o separador vai ser criado, faça da seguinte forma:

```
  ListView.separated(
    itemBuilder: (context, index){
      return Container(
          child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
          placeholder: kTransparentImage, 
          image: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["urlImagem"],
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      );
    },
    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
      height: 50,
      thickness: 0,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
  );
```

Assim, após cada item criado vai existir um separador.

Comment: Deu certinho aqui!!! Muito obrigado